# C++ Pointers Conversion

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I'm new to C++ programming so this question might be basic, but here it is:

I have four classes - A, B, C and D. Their relationships are as defined below:

```
class B : public A;
class D : public C;
```

A is an abstract class (all methods are pure virtual). Class D implements a Print() function which C does not.

```
//Class D - some code
void Print()
{
    //some code
}
```

Class A has an STL::list that holds pointers to objects of class C.

```
//Class A - some code
protected:
    list<C*> myObjects;
```

In class B I have a function which pushes to myObjects pointers to objects of type D (again, D inherits C) which works perfectly.

```
Class B : public A
{
    // Some code
    D* obj = new D(...);
    myObjects.push_back(obj);
    return obj;
}
```

Finally, in class B I have a function that iterates over myObjects (which is inherited from class A) like so:

```
for(list<C*>::iterator it = myObjects.begin(); it != myObjects.end(); it++)
{
    //I wish to call the function D.Print() but I get an error!
    D *a = *it;
    a->Print();
}
```

Error states:

```
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>' to 'D*'
```

I am under the impression that if "a" is a pointer to an object of class D, then if I give it the value of the pointer that is referenced by the iterator (which points to a pointer to an object of type D) I could call Print().

Can you help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @juanchopanza I tried that but since Print is not defined in class C, I get C2039: 'Print' : is not a member of C.

Comment: Sorry, i had missed that part. Then you need to try a `dynamic_cast`. It is better to have the relevant information in code, rather than prose.

Comment: Instead of just trying to explain what you have, with small out-of-context code snippets, why not create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can show us? It will make it much easier to understand what you have and what might be going on.

Comment: I will remember that for my next questions. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to attempt to cast to a `D` type if you define

```
virtual void Print() = 0;
```

in class `C`.

Then you can exploit polymorphism by writing

```
C *a = *it;
C->Print();
```

or, even better,

```
(*it)->Print();
```

If you can't do this then you *could* use a `dynamic_cast`, or simply store `list<D*> myObjects;` instead.

Comment: Apparently: "Class D implements a Print() function which C does not."

Comment: @jsantander: oops. Forgot to read the spec. Will not be the last time ;-)

Comment: I added virtual Print() = 0 and indeed problem solved! What if changinc C's API is not allowed?

Comment: If you can't change C's API *but* can change class `A`, then I'd redefine the list to `list<D*>`. Use `dynamic_cast` as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
D *a=dynamic_cast<D *>(*it)
```

The content of the list might be D objects, but that's only known at runtime, so the compiler cannot know at compile time if the list contain's D objects or other derived class from C.

For the record, this code compiled on [ideone](http://ideone.com/TuJSdW)

Comment: I get error C2683: 'dynamic_cast' : C is not a polymorphic type

Comment: @Tal You said that C has virtual methods... tried a dummy example with g++ and it worked.

Comment: I was wrong. A is abstract. C is not. Sorry for the confusion - I edited the original question.

Comment: then use static_cast instead.... however, depending on how you handle things... you probably would need a virtual destructor on C

Comment: This might be relevant: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `Print` is declared as pure virtual in `C`, and then just use the `C` pointer instead of `D` in your print loop. You do not need any casting, that's what virtual functions are for.